# Showing a form from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

So I have a static class containing this:

```
    public static void ShowErrorReport(Exception e, SqlCommand sqlc = null)
    {
        try
        {
            frmErrorReport frmER = new frmErrorReport(e, SqlCommand_: sqlc);
            frmER.ShowDialog();
            frmER.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Debug.Print(f.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I'd like to be able to use this from some database-related methods that run in a queued background worker. The problem is that those methods sometimes have no knowledge of any winforms objects, so using `Invoke()` isn't possible (as far as I can tell).

Is there any other way of calling this procedure from a backgroundworker thread and ensuring that the form is created on the UI thread?

Or am I going to have make a bit of a mess in those database methods by passing a winforms object through them (not looking forwards to that possibility!)?

I'm pretty new to multithreading...

Thanks

Comment: This is poor design. Better use events or exceptions. Also this is not related to multitrheading.

Comment: How would you use the exact code in a service, where no user can click your Dialog? Keep that in mind, even if you dont need it. It still helps to avoid problems like this.

Comment: @CSharpie I don't see where the OP said this was coming from a service.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to be able to use this from some database-related methods that run in a queued background worker. The problem is that those methods sometimes have no knowledge of any winforms objects, so using Invoke() isn't possible (as far as I can tell).

If your background code needs to interact with the UI you need to pass it some way to properly talk to the UI. Normally to abstract this away you create a "interaction service" you can pass in to your class and that interaction service then calls whatever UI technology you need.

```
public BackgroundClass
{
    public BackgroundClass(IInteractionService interactionService)
    {
        _interactionService = interactionService;
    }

    private readonly IInteractionService _interactionService;

    public static void ShowErrorReport(Exception e, SqlCommand sqlc = null)
    {
        try
        {
            _interactionService.ShowErrorReportDialog(e, sqlc);
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Debug.Print(f.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public interface IInteractionService
{
    void ShowErrorReportDialog(Exception e, SqlCommand cmd);
}

public class WinFormsInteractionService : IInteractionService
{
    public WinFormsInteractionService()
        this(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    {
    }

    public WinFormsInteractionService(SynchronizationContext syncContext)
    {
        if(syncContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("syncContext");
        _syncContext = syncContext;
    }

    private readonly SynchronizationContext _syncContext;

    public void ShowErrorReportDialog(Exception e, SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        _syncContext.Send(s => 
        {
            using(frmErrorReport frmER = new frmErrorReport(e, SqlCommand_: cmd))
            {
                frmER.ShowDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you ever decide to switch from Winforms to WPF or even to Console your `BackgroundClass` does not need to make any changes, you just need to make a new class that implements `IInteractionService` for whatever UI technology you are using.

```
public class ConsoleInteractionService : IInteractionService
{
    public WinFormsInteractionService()
    {
    }

    private readonly string _showErrorReportDialogFormatString = //...

    public void ShowErrorReportDialog(Exception e, SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_showErrorReportDialogFormatString, e, cmd);
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```